# EF Core 5 Owned type does not return saved data from database

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, asp.net5, value-objects, ef-core-5.0

I'm implementing a small project aplying DDD on it, but I'm having problems with Value Objects.

I have the following **Term** entity:

```
public class Term : Entity<TermId>, IAggregateRoot
{

    #region Properties

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateRange EnrollmentDates { get; set; }
    public DateRange TermDates { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Property Setters

    public void SetCode(string code) => Code = code;

    public void SetDescription(string description) => Description = description;

    public void SetEnrollmentDates(DateRange enrollmentDates) => EnrollmentDates = enrollmentDates;

    public void SetTermDates(DateRange termDates) => TermDates = termDates;

    #endregion

    #region Ctors

    public Term()
    {
        //EnrollmentDates = new DateRange(System.DateTime.Now, System.DateTime.Now);
        //TermDates = new DateRange(System.DateTime.Now, System.DateTime.Now);
    }

    public Term(TermId termId, string code, string description, DateRange enrollmentDates, DateRange termDates)
    {
        Id = termId;
        Code = code;
        Description = description;
        EnrollmentDates = enrollmentDates;
        TermDates = termDates;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods



    #endregion

}
```

And this is my **DateRange** value object:

```
public class DateRange : ValueObject
{

    #region Properties

    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Ctor

    private DateRange()
    {

    }

    public DateRange(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ValueObject Implementation

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return From;
        yield return To;
    }

    #endregion

}
```

With the following EF Configuration:

```
public class TermConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Term>
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures every property in Term Object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="builder">EntityTypeBuilder object</param>
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Term> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(u => u.Id);

        builder
            .Property(u => u.Id)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new TermId(x));

        builder
            .Ignore(x => x.DomainEvents);

        builder
            .Property(u => u.Code)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        builder
            .HasIndex(x => x.Code)
            .IsUnique();

        builder
            .Property(u => u.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        builder.OwnsOne<DateRange>(p => p.EnrollmentDates, b =>
        {
            //b.WithOwner();

            b
                .Property(p => p.From)
                .HasColumnName("EnrollmentStartingDate")
                .IsRequired();

            b
                .Property(p => p.To)
                .HasColumnName("EnrollmentEndingDate")
                .IsRequired();
        })/*.Navigation(p => p.EnrollmentDates).IsRequired()*/;

        builder.OwnsOne<DateRange>(p => p.TermDates, b =>
        {
            //b.WithOwner();

            b
                .Property(p => p.From)
                .HasColumnName("TermStartingDate")
                .IsRequired();

            b
                .Property(p => p.To)
                .HasColumnName("TermEndingDate")
                .IsRequired();
        })/*.Navigation(p => p.TermDates).IsRequired()*/;

    }

}
```

With the previous configuration, I can save a term with EnrollmentDates and TermDates, but when I want to retrieve this data from DB, value objects are null. When I call **_termRepository.GetAll();** EF makes the following SQL Query, so it is correct:

```
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Code], [t].[Description], [t].[EnrollmentStartingDate], [t].[EnrollmentEndingDate], [t].[TermStartingDate], [t].[TermEndingDate] FROM [Terms] AS [t]
```

I've been trying everything I've found on the internet with no luck. I'm using ASP.NET 5.0 and EF Core 5.0.9. Is there anything I'm missing or something?

**Source Code updated with last changes**

**Update with a solution:**

I've been trying some things and I found out a solution, at least in my case. I changed the Term identity configuration, and then, it takes everything from database.

This is the old configuration:

```
            builder
            .Property(u => u.Id)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new TermId(x));
```

This is the new configuration that works for me:

```
builder
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => new TermId(value),
                new ValueComparer<TermId>(
                    (l, r) => l.Value == r.Value,
                    v => v.Value.GetHashCode(),
                    v => new TermId(v.Value)));
```

Comment: Try adding private parameterless constructor to `DateRange` class and see if that helps.

Comment: @IvanStoev still null with a private parameterless constructor

Comment: all of your properties, except collections, need to have public getters AND setters, that's the EF way. get rid of those set methods, they are ugly and don't help. the standard rules of encapsulation don't hold on DTOs. oh, and get rid of the constructors. trust me if you try to do it the way you're doing it you will constantly be banging your head against a wall. encapsulation should come higher up.

Comment: @satnhak thanks for your comment, I'll take it into account. This is just a small project that serves me as a training and helps me to understand a little bit more about ddd implemented with c#. Regarding your answer, I've changed all the properties to be public and still getting null values.

Comment: DDD is something that you would do at a level above your DTOs. Yes, you want your data model to represent the business as faithfully as possible, but DTOs shouldn't ever get exposed to you API. You need to write them exactly the way that the ORM wants you to.

Don't mix your domain model and your DTOs, your domain model is a layer on top of your DTOs. Focus on getting the data in and out first. To me it looks like you are over complicating your data model with OwnsOne, just have two columns, from and to.

Comment: I think you should get rid of `.Navigation(p => ...).IsRequired();` Navigation is for navigating between different tables, but owned entities live in the same table.

Comment: @CKK The Navigation ... Required is fine.  It's needed to mark Value Object properties as required in addition to marking the actual properties themselves as required.

Comment: And you CAN have private setters, EF can assign to them as easy as to public ones. And it's perfectly fine to do so. Ideally, domain models and persistence models should be separate models, but then you would lose EF change tracking. So most people use the same set of objects for both domain and persistence.

Comment: @Miguel The code appears fine.  Have you tried using `p => p.TermDates` instead of string`"TermDates"` (same for EnrollmentDates) when configuring the owned type?  Either should normally work, but I note that the Navigation using the property expression, but the owned type is initially defined using a string.

Comment: @Miguel And, I note that you've used "WithOwner".  I've only ever found the need to use WithOwner() when I'm dealing with a collection of owned types.  Any joy, if you remove WithOwner()?

Comment: @NeilW isn't it enough to mark properties `From` and `To` as required? I mean, in the actual table there are no columns for `EnrollmentDates` and `TermDates`, right?

Comment: @CKK I don't think so.  Have been down that road previously and such items were still marked a nullable in the database.  Adding Navigiation ... Required fixed that.  Maybe it's been changed in a later version of EF.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Finally, removing Navigation as @CKK said it worked!

Comment: Ups!! Thought it worked but not!, I was trying some things and one of those was to initialize both value objects on Term entity, and now, when I retrieve data from db, it gives me a Date.Now, but not the dates from database.... So i'm at the same point... ;(

Comment: I took off WithOwner and Navigations and it does not work. Changing "TermDates" to p => p.TermDates neither